# Can I add time with date in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Can I add time with date in mysql ?

( e.g. date=2017-04-05 00:00:39 and time=00:10:00 
result should be 2017-04-05 00:10:39 )

I have tried

```
SELECT dateadd(start_time,max_bidding_time) from product;
```

Comment: You want to add or select the date? Try using 
`datetime = CONCAT(date, ' ', time);`

Comment: use `SELECT date_add("2017-04-05 00:00:39",INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) FROM Product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [ADD_TIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function:

```
SELECT ADDTIME('2017-04-05 00:00:39', '00:10:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
ADDTIME(start_time, DATE_FORMAT(time,'%H:%i:%s')) AS updatetime 
FROM product;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can change the structure of your table date field. Select type like "datetime" in database.[image]